# How to de Select ExtJS component programmatically.

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using Checkbox selection model in my extJS grid

```
selModel: {
        selType: 'checkboxmodel',
    },
```

I want my grid to be deselect programitcally.

Use case : 
Suppose that I click on a button that time any of the selected cell can be deselect. (There is some logic behind that.)

Thanks for help.

Comment: [Please have a look into the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel.html#method-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deselect programatically  then there is some option in extJS called `deselect` [Check Doc Here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.selection.Model.html#method-deselect)

You can write your code like this.

```
var gridSelction = grid.getSelection();
    for(var i=0; i<gridSelction.length; i++){ // For MultiSelection
        if(Your logic){
            grid.selModel.deselect(gridSelction[i])
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You've missed the [deselectAll](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.selection.Model.html#method-deselectAll) method..

Comment: @scebotari66 `deselectAll` will deselect all the row. I thought he is asking for single row  which he mentioned in question.

Comment: Yes I need to delete one cell. @UDID Thank u

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `mode` config of the `checkboxmodel` selection model. This way when ever you select something new, the previous selection gets unchecked.
Docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel.html#cfg-mode

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
      data: [{
          name: 'Lisa',
          email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
          phone: '555-111-1224'
      }, {
          name: 'Bart',
          email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
          phone: '555-222-1234'
      }, {
          name: 'Homer',
          email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
          phone: '555-222-1244'
      }, {
          name: 'Marge',
          email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
          phone: '555-222-1254'
      }]
  });

  Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
      title: 'Simpsons',
      store: store,
      columns: [{
          text: 'Name',
          dataIndex: 'name'
      }, {
          text: 'Email',
          dataIndex: 'email',
          flex: 1
      }, {
          text: 'Phone',
          dataIndex: 'phone'
      }],
      height: 200,
      width: 400,
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      selModel: {
          selType: 'checkboxmodel',
          mode: 'SINGLE'

      }
  });
```

Comment: NO I need a multiple selection. Suppose I selected three checkbox and on click of button second selection is gone. Something like that

Comment: I really need a flow description, I do not understand exactly what you need. Do that and I will adept my anwsere

Comment: @BogdanM. It's actually quite simple. He needs mode MULTI and then he needs to deselect several selected rows based on an event.